# Return data from struct and enum

Tags: swift, collections, sprite-kit

I'm making a small app where users can see certain info regarding an animal. For that I have a function that is returning the texture for each animal.

Since this is going to contain a lot of animals from different areas like sea, forrests etc I'm trying to make a struct for the area and an enum for all the animals.

However, I'm having a little trouble making it work. I get this error:

> Type 'allAnimals' has no member 'bull'

Any help is appreciated! :-)

```
struct allAnimals {
    // Farm animals
    let farmAnimals : farmAnimals

    // Sea animals
    let seaAnimals : seaAnimals
}

enum farmAnimals {
    case bull, cat, chicken, cow, duck, drake, goose, horse, mouse, peacock, pig, rooster, sheep
}

enum seaAnimals {
    case starfish, oyster, whale
}


func returnAnimalTexture(forAnimal: allAnimals) -> SKTexture {
    switch forAnimal {
    case .bull:
        // Return SKTexture
    case .cat:
        // Return SKTexture
    case .starfish:
        // Return SKTexture
    }
}

// Get specific texture
let animalTexture = returnAnimalTexture(forAnimal: allAnimals.bull)
```

Comment: what is producing the error? You haven't mentioned the error.

Comment: My bad - forgot to add it. Has been edited now :-)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you got your concepts a bit mixed up.

---

```
struct allAnimals {
    // Farm animals
    let farmAnimals : farmAnimals

    // Sea animals
    let seaAnimals : seaAnimals
}
```

In this struct, you create an `allAnimal`, which has 1 type from `farmAnimals` and 1 type from `seaAnimals` enum, like:

```
let chimera = allAnimal(farmAnimals: .horse, .seaAnimals: .whale)
```

---

You probably want something like:

```
enum FarmAnimal {
    case bull
    case horse
}

enum SeaAnimal {
    case fish
}

enum AnimalType {
    case farm(farmAnimalType: FarmAnimal)
    case sea(seaAnimalType: SeaAnimal)
}
```

Then you can write your function like:

```
func texture(of animal: AnimalType) -> SKTexture {
    switch animal {
    case let .farm(farmAnimalType):
        switch farmAnimalType {
        case .bull:
            print("Bull")
        case .horse:
            print("Horse")
        }
    case let .sea(seaAnimalType):
        switch seaAnimalType {
        case .fish:
            print("Fish")
        }
    }
}
```

---

**However, you're not doing anything with the fact that the animal is a `farm` or `sea` animal. So you might as well just put all of them into a single `enum Animal`**